# NGNIX Backward Proxy for a Nextcloud URL redirect failure

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, proxy, nextcloud

I have a little problem concerning my nginx setup. I plan to create multiple in a network with one central server as a proxy.

```
                         |---(/nextcloud/)--->Nextcloud-Server
-----> Central-Server--->|
                         |---(/git)---------->Git-Server
                         |
                         |---(/Redmine)---------->Redmine-Server
```

I started this setup with my Nextcloud Server for some reason URL redirects are not working properly. I tried to used several redirect and rewrite rules but could not get it working.

When accessing a location I always get redirected to the Central Server. So domain.net/nextcloud/ will be redirected to domain.net/login, but it should actually access domain.net/nextcloud/login. Does anyone have solution for this? My current config looks like

```
    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
server {
    listen       192.168.178.10:443 ssl;
    server_name  domain.net;
#root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    ssl_certificate /mnt/docker/nginx/certs/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /mnt/docker/nginx/certs/privkey.pem;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf/ssl_params;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
    ssl_session_timeout 15m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

    #add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=<HSTS_MAX_AGE>;<HSTS_SUBDOMAINS><HSTS_PRELOAD>";
    client_max_body_size 10G;

    location /n/ {
        alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

location /nextcloud/ {
    access_log off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real_ip $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass https://192.168.178.11/;
}


    location ^~ /c{
   rewrite ^/c(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass https://192.168.178.11/;
       proxy_connect_timeout 1;
       proxy_set_header        Host              $http_host;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
    }
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
 }

}
}
```

Comment: I am using this set up might could help: https://github.com/evertramos/docker-compose-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion along with https://github.com/evertramos/docker-nextcloud-letsencrypt

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

```
upstream nextcloud {
    server 127.0.0.1:8209
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name www.abc.xyz;

    ssl_certificate server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key server.key;
    ssl_client_certificate  ca.crt;


    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;


    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }


     rewrite ^/core/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/core/$1 last;
     rewrite ^/apps/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/apps/$1 last;
     rewrite ^/js/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/js/$1 last;
     rewrite ^/css/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/css/$1 last;
     rewrite ^/ocs/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/ocs/$1 last;
     rewrite ^/settings/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/settings/$1 last;
     rewrite ^/remote.php/(.+?)$ /nextcloud/remote.php/$1 last;

     rewrite ^/login(.*)$ /nextcloud/login$1 last;
     rewrite ^/lostpassword(.*)$ /nextcloud/lostpassword$1 last;

     location /nextcloud {
      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          http://nextcloud/;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      https://www.abc.xyz https://www.abc.xyz/nextcloud;
     }
}
```

Just for next cloud, which git server do you chose?

```
gitlab-ce supply relative url
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html

external_url "https://gitlab.example.com" -> "https://gitlab.example.com/git"